# Is it possible to display Percentage values group wise instead of total in tableau

Tags: data-visualization, visualization, tableau-desktop

My current bar plot looks like :

[image]

The percentage is calculated for whole dataset.
I need to know percentage group wise for all income categories.
I am able to achieve the same one by one with the use of filter:
[image]

But I need to get the percent values for each group in first barplot.
That is, 77.69% - 22.31% in first diagram.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the functionality by right clicking the Text - CNT(Is Churn) and using the compute using functionality :

[image]